# how to pass Authorization Bearer token as header parameter in swagger doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, openapi

i am trying to pass Bearer Authorization token through header in swagger doc but i'm not receiving the header,

this doesn't include header when i log the request

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *   securitySchemes:
 *     BearerAuth:
 *       type: http
 *       scheme: bearer
 *       bearerFormat: JWT

 * /api/v1/mediator/verify/phone/otp:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Verify Phone OTP
 *     tags: [Users]
 *     security:
 *       - BearerAuth: []
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               phone_number:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The phone number to verify OTP.
 *               code:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The OTP code to verify.
 *     responses:
 *       '200':
 *         description: Phone OTP verification successful.
 *       '400':
 *         description: Bad request - validation failed or phone_number/code not provided.
 *       '401':
 *         description: Unauthorized - Missing or invalid token. This endpoint requires a bearer token for authorization.
 *       '500':
 *         description: Internal server error.
 */
```

this doesn't pop up any required field for me to pass the Authorization token

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/v1/mediator/verify/email/otp:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Verify Email OTP
 *     tags: [Users]
 *     security:
 *       - BearerAuth: []
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: header
 *         name: Authorization
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *           format: BearerToken
 *           description: Bearer token for authorization.
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               email:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The phone number to verify OTP.
 *               code:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The OTP code to verify.
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Phone OTP verification successful.
 *       400:
 *         description: Bad request - validation failed or email/code not provided.
 *       401:
 *         description: Unauthorized - invalid or missing token.
 *       500:
 *         description: Internal server error.
 */
```

i'm i doing anything wrong here, i'm using openapi 3.0.0, when i try this using postman it works fine but doesn't work on swagger, i'm on able to receive any parameters from the header.

Comment: Try to add a component in the doc for security as shown in do : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/

Comment: did that but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a corrected version:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *   securitySchemes:
 *     BearerAuth:
 *       type: http
 *       scheme: bearer
 *       bearerFormat: JWT
 *
 * /api/v1/mediator/verify/phone/otp:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Verify Phone OTP
 *     tags: [Users]
 *     security:
 *       - BearerAuth: []
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               phone_number:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The phone number to verify OTP.
 *               code:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The OTP code to verify.
 *     responses:
 *       '200':
 *         description: Phone OTP verification successful.
 *       '400':
 *         description: Bad request - validation failed or phone_number/code not provided.
 *       '401':
 *         description: Unauthorized - Missing or invalid token. This endpoint requires a bearer token for authorization.
 *       '500':
 *         description: Internal server error.
 */
```

Comment: this is only accepting the parameters of phone_number and code, but there is no field for me to pass in the Bearer token in headers,
```
headers:{
Authorization:'Bearer Token'
}
```

Comment: this sample is correct and the use of the security object implies the `authorization` header is defined.  where are you expecting to see the field?